# Visualizar estadisticas sql con javamelody y mssql

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy tratando de configurar javamelody para que muestre estadísticas las querys que lanzo contra mssql. El entorno del proyecto está conformado por las siguientes tecnologías:

- Java jdk 1.8
- Tomcat 9.0.0.M15
- Javamelody 1.70.0
- Hibernate 5.2.12.Final
- Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

El fichero de configuración **web.xml** contiene la siguiente configuración para javamelody:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

...

<!-- Configuración de javamelody -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <distributable/>

    ...

</web-app>
```

Por otra parte, el fichero de configuración de **hibernate** tiene la siguiente configuración de acceso a base de datos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=****;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>

        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Esta misma configuración funciona para mysql (obviamente modificando los parámetros de conexión), sin embargo con Microsoft SQL Server no he conseguido visualizar las estadisticas de las consultas.